# reading a webpage html source code and adding table into arrays with php

Tags: php, html, parsing

im trying to read a webpage's source code and add an information of a table into arrays

The webpage is http://dsrd.uc.cl/dara/libcursos/periodo21/ua5_1.html

Within the table, i want to add the column "profesores" into an array profesores[] and the column "nombre asignatura" into an array curso[];

I know I can get the webpage source coude with:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

but I have no idea into how to manage the string to create the arrays.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use DOMDocument:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($homepage);
$table = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(/* Find out which one it is */)
$rows = $table->getElementByTagName("tr")
for ($i = 0; $i length; $i++)
{
    $row = $rows->item($i);
    /* Find columns and add it to your array */
}
```